# Как правильно стилизовать кнопку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, стилизация

Помогите, пожалуйста, стилизовать кнопку, чтобы при наведении курсора она и текст внутри не прыгали.

Изначально кнопка должна быть с тонкой линией на фоне, а в ховере появляется полный фон 40px высотой.

[песочница на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xa2fkmud)

```css
.btn-container {
  height: 40px;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;    
    width: 220px;
    height: 8px;
   background-color: #f0c52e;    
    text-align: center;    
}

.btn:hover {
    width: 220px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <a class="btn" href="#">More about us</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправленный вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/vay02592/

Можно обойтись без контейнера для кнопки, а стилизацию сделать через фон .btn:before.

```
.btn:before {
    background-color: #f0c52e;
    bottom: 16px;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 16px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.btn:hover:before {
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Изначально кнопка должна быть с тонкой линией на фоне, а в ховере появляется полный фон 40px высотой(

Comment: Извиняюсь, не сохранил fiddle перед последней правкой. Исправлено.

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Comment: gambala ещё бы transition не большой , ваще атас получится

Comment: @Geyan, готово, с transition, по той же ссылке

Comment: gambala ляпота! я даже ссылку в google+ отправлю